# Fetching data from sap to salesforce using apex class

Tags: apex

Im new in apex,Im integrating SFDC TO SAP SD using WSDL. I want the apex class code for to get records from SAP SD (VBAK-KUNNR,VBAK-VBELN,VBAK-BSTNK,VBAK-BSTKD,VBAK-NETWR,VBAK-WAERK)

Answer (score 1):

If SAP has published WSDL files describing there messages you need to generate the APEX code from those WSDLs using WSDL2Apex

This is described in the 2nd half of this blog entry:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

You can then use the generated Apex to programmatically call out.

I would also advice you to read this document:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_patterns/integration_patterns_and_practices.pdf

And I would also note that there are formats/structures of Some WSDLs which are not Salesforce compatible.  This document has a good overview:  http://techblog.appirio.com/2013/02/best-practices-for-apex-callouts.html